# fade effect for background screen while pop up opens using Flex 4 and as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flex4

How can I set Faded effect for mobile screen using flex 4 and action script 3. when the pop up window open, the background Mobile screen must be dim (Fade) and when I close pop up window, then screen again come back normal mode.  How can I do this ? I tried with s:transitions but I couldn't achieve this. thanks in Advance.

Comment: For little inspiration you may consult the this code: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/02/27/setting-effects-with-actionscript-in-flex/. It's not quite what you need but you can work on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a view thats 100% width and height with a grey/black background and only add it to the displayList when the popup is opened.  Start alpha at 0 and gradually increase its opacity and this should create something similar to what you are looking for.